# Unable to rsync between server with a specific user

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync

I have two Linux machines and i am trying to sync a file between the two of them using 'rsync'.

I have generated a key on the client machine using:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

And then copied the public key to the `/home/user1/.ssh/authorized_keys` and `/home/user2/.ssh/authorized_keys` files.

I am able to rsync a file to user1 using the next command:

```
rsync -a /home/user/sendIt.txt user1@some.host:/home/user1/
```

However, when I am trying to use rsync to sync a file to the second user using :

```
rsync -a /home/user/sendIt.txt user2@some.host:/home/user2/
```

I receive this error:

```
protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
(see the rsync man page for an explanation)
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(171) [sender=3.0.6]
```

Why am I able to sync to one user but not to the other? I should mention that the second user is designed to be used as a SFTP user only, and he is jailed to his home directory.

Any thoughts of how to fix it and avoid it in the future?
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Check rsync version of user2 in jail.

Comment: @DanyLavrov: if the jailed user2 haven't got `rsync` binary in his home, then ssh also can't find and run it.

Comment: Ok. inside the `.bashrc` file i have the next thign `if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi`. What should i do with it? 

If it does not have rsync binary in the home directory of user2? how would i put it in there.
Sorry for all the question, just haven't had this issue before.

Comment: The thing is that i don't see any `rsync` binary in the home directory of the first user as well but i can still sync to it.

Comment: How did you implement '_designed to be used as a SFTP_'?

Comment: Will i be able to undo this in case it wont do any good?
@sborsky I have basically created a new user and followed the steps as described in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052875/setting-up-ftp-on-amazon-cloud-server) this post , answer by Iman Sedighi.

Answer (score 1):

You restricted access for user2 to SFTP only. Thus `rsync` is not allowed.

To solve this, you would have to undo the restriction to SFTP in `sshd_config`.

Instead - to only allow `rsync` - you could write a script which checks if the command to be run is `rsync` and set `ForceCommand` to this script in your `sshd_config`.

See also [this serverfault.com question/answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/323501/sshd-config-forcecommand-usr-bin-rsync-error-connection-unexpectedly-closed#323504).

Comment: Ok, thank you.
I have restricted the access of the user to SFTP only because that is what i need for him. What would be the best way for me to put files inside his home folder using rsync but still keep him restricted to it? Will i be able to to sync the files to a directory under user1 ownership and then use rsycn to copy it to his home directory (on the same machine)? Or this will end up giving me the same error?

Comment: So basically, if i will write the exact rsync command that i am trying to execute `rsync -a /home/user/sendIt.txt user2@some.host:/home/user2/`  next to the ForceCommand it will allow its execution?

Comment: Will it have any side effect on the fact that this user needs to be restricted to this specific directory? Will this user still be able to connect and pull file using the sftp?

Answer (score 0):

As stated earlier by @sborsky, you can't `rsync` because your server config is restricted to SFTP.  You should however be able to use `sshfs` and mount the remote directory locally and `rsync` to that mounted directory.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

At first i have tried the `ForceCommand` approach but that was not working for me.
What i did eventually is to create a directory inside the directory user2 jailed/bind to. This directory is owned by user1, and i am able to rsync files into it.

The process is as follows:
user2 was jailed / chrooted using

```
Match Group sftponly
        ChrootDirectory /var/ftp
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
```

inside `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

This directory was bind to his home directory using:

```
mount --bind /var/ftp /home/user2/ftp
```

Then inside `/var/ftp/` i did:

```
mkdir tempDir
chown -R user1:user1 tempDir
```

Once the files are synced to that directory they automatically appear in the user2 jail directory and he can read them.